# Swipe finger gesture in tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

In tab bar, if I do a single tap on tab bar, the label should read some quote.

similarly it should recognize these touch gestures and display the text in the label :

1) double tap 2) 1 finger : top to bottom swipe.
  3) 2 finger : tab to up swipe
which method to use and how to use?

Answer (score 0):

[UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the place to dig in.

Comment: There is a link in the answer that will take you to the Apple documentation. There you will find how to use it.